# Inheriting a non-abstract class and turning all of its functions into abstractmethods

Tags: python, inheritance, abstract-class

An upstream interface was given to me with all of its functions defined as non-abstract when in reality they should be decorated with `@abstractmethod`s. I want to receive an error when I did not implement one of its functions when it's called. To do this, I would create a wrapper class and manually go through each of its defined functions and do something like this:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class Foo(object):
    def foo(self):
        print("Foo")

class AbstractFoo(Foo, ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def foo(self):
        return super().foo()

class ConcreteFoo(AbstractFoo):
    def foo(self):
        print("Concrete Foo")
        super().foo()

f = ConcreteFoo()
f.foo()
```

Which outputs:

```
Concrete Foo
Foo
```

I would like some way of just doing this to *all* functions defined by Foo. Obviously, inherited magic functions like `__str__` and `__repr__` should be forwarded appropriately.

Does anyone know a nice, pythonic way of doing this?

Comment: m... I have an idea using decorator, is it valid for you? meaning not on run-time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def validate_base_class_implemntation(cls):
    base_cls_funcs = []
    for attr in cls.__bases__[0].__dict__:
        if callable(getattr(cls, attr)):
            base_cls_funcs.append(attr)

    cls_funcs = []
    for attr in cls.__dict__:
        if callable(getattr(cls, attr)):
            cls_funcs.append(attr)

    missing_funcs = [x for x in base_cls_funcs if x not in cls_funcs]

    if len(missing_funcs) > 0:
        print("Not implemented functions are: {}".format(','.join(missing_funcs)))
        raise Exception("Not implement function exception!")

    return cls


class Foo(object):
    def foo(self):
        print("Foo")

    def boo(self):
        print("Wow")


@validate_base_class_implemntation
class ConcreteFoo(Foo):
    def foo(self):
        print("Concrete Foo")
        super().foo()


f = ConcreteFoo()
f.foo()
```

Not sure in 100% if that what you meant.

this decorator checks that the class decorated implements all the base class function(in your case, they are not decorated with abstract). if there is a function that your decorated class does not implement, it raises exception.

Comment: This works for me! Thanks so much for this implementation. I wonder if there's a more pythonic way to do this, but this is definitely sufficient for me :) cheers!

Comment: @OneRaynyDay I'll think about it

Comment: @OneRaynyDay More pythonic: (1) Using `set` instead of `list` for the funcs, then `missing_funcs = base_cls_funcs - cls_funcs`, (2) Checking `if missing_funcs` is sufficient, (3) Using `cls.mro()[1]` instead of `cls.__bases__[0]`, (4) Using `vars(...)` instead of `__dict__`, (5) Using a comprehension instead of the two `for` loops, (6) Raise a `TypeError` instead of `Exception`. Also `callable` will include non-function objects so `isinstance(..., types.FunctionType)` is more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the original class `Foo` and turn all its methods into abstract methods and then define a blank subclass of `Foo` with `metaclass=ABCMeta` in order to handle the checks:

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod
from types import FunctionType


class AbstractFoo(Foo, metaclass=ABCMeta):
    pass


names = set()
for k, v in vars(Foo).items():
    if k.startswith('__') and k.endswith('__'):
        continue
    elif isinstance(v, FunctionType):
        names.add(k)
        v.__isabstractmethod__ = True

AbstractFoo.__abstractmethods__ = frozenset(names)
```

**Side note:** This approach relies on dunder attributes being used by `abc` and as such can break without deprecation.

Comment: Thanks for this implementation! In the problem statement I should've mentioned that `Foo` may not be directly inheriting `object`, which means there may be non-dunders that I don't want to make abstract. This would apply to every function. I have upvoted your answer though! Apologies for the incomplete specification

Comment: @OneRaynyDay I'm not sure I understand what you mean. `vars(Foo)` checks only the *immediate* attributes of `Foo` excluding any base classes. In case `Foo` itself defines methods that you don't want to turn abstract then, for any algorithm, you need to provide some specification for them.